# Blueprint site completely different in IE compared to Firefox/Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, blueprint-css

I'm using the Blueprint CSS framework to develop my website to ensure cross-browser compatability...except, it looks completely different in IE.

The site is http://rtwilson.com/academic-new/ and looks fine in Firefox and Chrome, but completely messed up in IE. The main body is not centred, the image is in the wrong place and the text is rather weird.

Does anyone have any idea how I can sort this? I thought the whole point of Blueprint et al. was that it sorted the problems with cross-browser (particularly IE) compatibility. I have included the correct IE style file - so any other ideas?

Comment: This page is in Quirks Mode. Add a good `doctype`. The shortest possible form is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blueprint is fine (although I have recently switched to Twitter Bootstrap)- regardless of the complexity of the site, and it does do all of the things for you, as long as your markup is correct and the classes are used correctly.

One place to start, other than the doctype (which should be added, as well - as mentioned by Michas), would be to add a "last" class to the div that contains your navbar div.  The way you have it written right now is that you have a span-24, containing another span-24 immediately followed by a span-15 and a span-9.

You have:

```
    <div class="span-24 last">
        <div class="span-24">
        ...
        </div> 
        <div class="span-15">
                ...
        </div>
        <div class="span-9 last">
                ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

You *should* have:

```
    <div class="span-24 last">
        <div class="span-24 last">
        ...
        </div> 
        <div class="span-15">
                ...
        </div>
        <div class="span-9 last">
                ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

As it is written now, I would not be in the least bit surprised that IE can't figure out that there shouldn't be 48 spans in a single row.

Comment: I noticed that you updated your site to include the "last" class, mentioned above.  You will notice that it still looks off unless you are in compatibility mode in IE.  You should add at least a minimal, valid doctype delcaration at the top of your markup to prevent IE from dropping into quirks mode.

Comment: thanks. I'd added the doctype before but then managed to overwrite it with an old version of the file. Ooops! Thanks for pointing out that it still wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

If I am being honest, I wouldn't use blueprint css - a site simple as yours I would simply just create a seperate stylesheet for IE, and link it like this

```
<!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although that would require me knowing all of the things I need to do differently for IE. I thought part of the reason for Blueprint was that it does all of that for you?